# What is the most read efficient way to allow "approved" users to read data in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have two classes of users - approved and unapproved. Both have authenticated with Firebase, but approved is allowed to read a broader class of documents than unapproved is. One way I could implement this is by storing a document for each user with their approved status, and then checking `/users/{uid}` for `status=="Approved"` in the Firestore rules as the read condition. However, this would double the amount of reads in my project and thus my costs with respect to reads - is there a more efficient way to do this? It isn't scalable to hardcode the UIDs into the security rules.

Comment: Without a custom claim in the authentication token (and it should be discouraged to use this method - authentication is for _authentication_, not _authorization_), this is the most efficient way that I can think of. The issue with using a custom claim would present itself, for instance, when the user still holds a valid authentication token but is moved into either "approved" or "unapproved" statuses. There's no need to reauthenticate or a fool-proof way to force reauthentication, but their previous valid token will not contain the updated claim.

Comment: @j1mbl3s can't I revoke the refresh token in that case?

Comment: Yes, the admin API allows [revoking refresh tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#revokerefreshtokens), but refresh tokens are for refreshing the authentication state with a new authentication token, once the current has expired. It does not revoke current authentication tokens.

Comment: Hmm if I force a password reset would it revoke the current authentication token?

Comment: No, any current valid authentication tokens will not be revoked. There is no way to revoke authentication tokens without a system that stores records of issued authentication tokens, but this is not provided by Firebase. However, after further reading, Firebase documentation itself does mention that [custom claims can be used for controlling access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) (as previously mentioned, this is possible but not fool-proof). After pondering the problem a bit more, I will add an answer with a possible method using custom claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase allows setting of [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) within user authentication tokens, which is available to Firestore rules via the [`request.auth.token`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth) map. Although it is not typical to use authentication tokens in an authorization context, because previously-issued authentication tokens will remain valid until their expiration in most systems (after which a refresh token can be used to obtain a new authentication token), you could potentially use this method along with a document listener to listen for updates to the user status in order to force a token refresh.

##### Example

###### Cloud Functions document listener

This listens to the user's document to set a claim via the admin API when the `status` is changed:

```js
import functions from 'firebase-functions';
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

export const updateUserStatusClaim = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const statusAfter = change.after.data().status;
    if (change.before.data().status !== statusAfter) {
      const userId = context.params.userId;
      const auth = admin.auth();

      auth.getUser(userId)
        .then((user) => {
          const updatedCustomClaims = Object.assign(
            {},
            user.customClaims,
            { status: statusAfter }
          );
          auth.setCustomUserClaims(userId, updatedCustomClaims)
            .then(() => {
              // Update another document for the client listener.
              // This makes sure that the client does not refresh
              // before the custom claims are set.
              admin.firestore()
                .doc(`userClaims/${userId}`)
                .set(
                  { status: statusAfter },
                  { merge: true }
                );
            });
        });
    }
  });
```

###### Note

There is an asynchronous issue using this method for updating the claims:

- (A.1) creates an updatedCustomClaims object with updated `status`.
- (B.1) creates an updatedCustomClaims object with updated `otherClaim` (does not contain the updated `status`).
- (A.2) sets the user's custom claims.
- (B.2) sets the user's custom claims.

The user's custom claims would not contain the updated `status`, but would contain the updated `otherClaim`.

A better method would be to use a separate document for storage of the user's custom claims, along with another document for clients to listen to.
Even this method may have asynchronous issues, though:

- (A.3) handles the write event for the claims document, updated with `status`.
- (B.3) handles the write event for the claims document, updated with `otherClaim` (and `status`).
- (B.4) sets the user's custom claims.
- (A.4) sets the user's custom claims.

The user's custom claims would not contain the updated `otherClaim`, but would contain the updated `status`.

###### Client document listener

This listens to the `userClaims` document for changes. This document is updated only after the custom user claims have been set by the Cloud Functions document listener:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';

// assuming you have already called firebase.initializeApp()
const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

let uid = undefined;
let userClaimsUnsubscriber = undefined;
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (
    userClaimsUnsubscriber !== undefined &&
    (user === null || user.uid !== uid)
  ) {
    if (user === null) {
      uid = undefined;
    }
    userClaimsUnsubscriber();
    userClaimsUnsubscriber = undefined;
  }
  if (user !== null && userClaimsUnsubscriber === undefined) {
    uid = user.uid;
    userClaimsUnsubscriber = firestore
      .doc(`userClaims/${uid}`)
      .onSnapshot({
        next: (snapshot) => {
          // Force the client to refresh the token.
          // In this example, we don't really care about
          // the returned Promise.
          user.getIdToken(true);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

As mentioned in a comment to the original post, there is no guarantee that a client will adhere to refreshing their token when the `userClaims` document is updated. So, if a user is moved from `approved` to `unapproved` status, they may still have access to approved user status functionality until their token naturally expires.